# What versions of JAR files should I download for my hadoop and spark cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a 3 node hadoop cluster on 3 Ubuntu EC2 instances, where I have Hadoop version 3.3.6, Apache Spark version 3.5.0 and hive version 3.1.3. And Im using postgres as my external metastore. Im able to read/write to local HDFS files, but I would like to read/write files to my S3. I have an instance profile role attached to all 3 nodes that has full access to my s3 bucket (full access). I have the following jar files in my /opt/spark/jars (related to hadoop and aws)

- aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
- hadoop-aws-3.3.5.jar
- aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.576.jar
- parquet-hadoop-1.13.1.jar
- hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.3.4.jar
- hadoop-shaded-guava-1.1.1.jar
- hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.4.jar
- hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar

Im not a java developer, so I do not know much about JAR files, I read a lot of medium posts and stack overflow posts, and downloaded the jars and stored them in /opt/spark/jars directory. Can someone help me with the correct version of Jars, I need to download, so that I can read/write to my S3 bucket. Also I would like to implement access control for my cluster, I know this is a separate topic, but any pointers on this would be helpful. I looked at apache submarine, but yet to try it, I looked at Cloudera's implementation but that proprietary, Databricks UC is also proprietary. Im looking for some open source. Hope you can help.

I tried using the above car JAR files and I ran into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2316, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2291, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2044, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/impl/WeakRefMetricsSource
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.registerAsMetricsSource(S3AInstrumentation.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.<init>(S3AInstrumentation.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.impl.WeakRefMetricsSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using a long running EMR cluster as an alternative. Instead of setting up everything yourself.

Comment: have you followed the s3a troubleshooting guide yet? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: @user238607 - I didn't want to use EMR or databricks, I wanted to experiment with open source spark for my understanding.

Comment: @stevel - Thanks for the link. I didn't see that. but now that I look at it, it's got a lot of information about general troubleshooting. in my case I just don't know how to select the correct version of Jar files that matches my Hadoop, Spark and Hive version.

Comment: I don't consider configuring system as learning it unless I am required to do it because of onprem requirement etc. I would rather first focus on using the framework properly, optimizations etc and then put my effort on jars and stuff.

Comment: > in my case I just don't know how to select the correct version of Jar files that matches my Hadoop, Spark and Hive version. 
what the doc does say is "use the exact same hadoop versions unless you enjoy stack traces"

Comment: and afraid learning how to configure a system is key, as is learning how to debug from a stack trace. As is -to be utterly ruthless- learning how to search stack overflow before repeating a common question

Comment: Thanks all. Did find the exact location in the spark GitHub page. It's in the pom file. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.5.0/pom.xml